# How to test a class that implementing ContainerAwareInterface

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, php-7, symfony-2.8

I have a class like this

```
class MyClass implements ContainerAwareInterface
{
    public function construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
        $this->em = $entityManager;
    }

    public function doSomething()
    {
        $myService = $this->container->get('my.service.defnition.in.services.yaml');
    }

    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container = null)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }
}
```

and the test class with a test method

```
public function testDoSomething()
    {
        $manager = new MyClass($this->mockEm);
        $manager->doSomething();
    }
```

when I call doSomething() I get the error

`Call to a member function get() on null`

like the container is not set properly. I am pretty sure the class is configured properly as it runs correctly from the browser.
Any Idea plase?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `setContainer` in `testDoSomething` and mock a container instance.

Just a side note: if you can, stay away from container injection: it could be troublesome to test and you potentially bring a lot of hidden dependencies in your code.

Comment: can you provide an example or a link with some detail please?